# How to repopulate arraylist after it becomes empty when using it to randomize activities

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist

So i'm trying really hard to create a game and I keep coming up with roadblocks. I have each level as a separate activity and I got help from stackoverflow user Rohan in randomizing the way each activity starts. Now in order to avoid out of memory issues I have to use `finish()` or `Android:noHistory=true`...the problem I have is, when the game plays through all the activities randomly once, and the arraylist becomes empty, i don't know the code to repopulate the activity because the `finish()` or `Android:noHistory=true` code of every activity empties the arraylist.

MyActivity.java

```
    import android.app.Application;


    public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    ActivityList.init(23);
}}
```

ActivityList.java

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;


    public class ActivityList {

   private static ActivityList instance;

    private final ArrayList<Class> activities;
    public final int numActivities;

   public static void init(int numActivities) {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new ActivityList(numActivities);
  }

    private ActivityList(int numActivities) {
    this.numActivities = numActivities;
    activities = new ArrayList<>(numActivities);

        try {
             for(int i = 1 ; i <= numActivities ; i++) {
                 activities.add(Class.forName   ("com.game.thegame.Q" + i));
        }
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Collections.shuffle(activities);
}

public static ActivityList getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

public Class getRandomActivity() {
    if (activities.isEmpty()) {  //(I think I should add something here)

        return EndScreen.class;

    }

    Class clazz = activities.get(0);
    activities.remove(0);

    return clazz;
   }
        }
```

Q1.class

```
      Public void onbuttonClick(View v){
      Class activityToShow = ActivityList.getInstance().getRandomActivity();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityToShow);
    intent.putExtra("score", score);

    startActivity(intent);}
```

Comment: It would seem you are making a question game. In which case having N Activity classes for N questions seems like a bad design choice. As long as each question is the same format, you only need one single activity to render all N questions

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just call ActivityList.init(23); again like you did in the beginning?

Comment: Hey...thanks for taking the time to reply...all my activities are of different layout designs so I have to make them separate....where do I call Activitylist.Init(23)?...I'm a noob and if you could add it to the code that would be awesome..I tried different things and it failed...